# Why does adding a duration in seconds to a moment date give weird results for values past 1 month?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, datetime, momentjs, activesupport

I'm running into an issue with adding an amount of seconds to a [moment](https://momentjs.com/) date in my Rails app. I use [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/) for JS but that shouldn't relevant to the cause of the problem.

I've got a select form input that I've generated using the Rails form builder using these `options_for_select`:

```rb
[["1 day", 1.day], ["3 days", 3.days], ["7 days", 1.week],
["14 days", 2.weeks], ["1 month", 1.month],
["3 months", 3.months], ["6 months", 6.months], ["1 year", 1.year]]
```

That results in a select that looks like this:

```html
<select class="form-control" data-admin--reports-form-target="sendFrequencySelect"
<option value="86400">1 day</option>
<option value="259200">3 days</option>
<option value="604800">7 days</option>
<option value="1209600">14 days</option>
<option value="2629746">1 month</option>
<option value="7889238">3 months</option>
<option selected="selected" value="15778476">6 months</option>
<option value="31556952">1 year</option>
</select>
```

I have some JS that takes the value of the selected option and adds that amount of seconds to a moment date, and then sets the value of a different input to the new moment date that results from that calculation:

```js
let finalRunAt = moment(this.lastGeneratedTimestampInputTarget.value, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
let secondsToAdd = parseInt(this.sendFrequencySelectTarget.value);
finalRunAt.add(secondsToAdd, "seconds");
this.finalRunTimestampInputTarget.value = finalRunAt.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
```

This works correctly... until you get to 1 month or larger. Here's how the calculations come out for a start date of `2021-02-25 12:00`:

| Select option | Result of adding seconds to start date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 day | 2021-02-26 12:00 |
| 3 days | 2021-02-28 12:00 |
| 7 days | 2021-03-04 12:00 |
| 14 days | 2021-03-11 12:00 |
| 1 month | **2021-03-27 23:29** |
| 3 months | **2021-05-27 20:27** |
| 6 months | **2021-08-27 03:54** |
| 1 year | **2022-02-25 17:49** |

I've been trying to reverse-engineer the weird (bolded) results. What's causing these results? Is it some discrepancy between what Rails considers 1 month and what moment considers 1 month?

Comment: _"What's causing these results?"_ - Your numbers. `2629746` seconds are `30.436875` days and that's what moment is adding to the timestamp - `30` days and ~`10.48` hours

Comment: Also months don't all have the same number of seconds. That's really the wrong way to manipulate dates in JavaScript. The Date prototype has methods that correctly and consistently increment by time units.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, that the Rails 1-month-in-seconds is not actually 1-month-in-seconds on the JS end. I guess I'm mostly curious why the Rails-provided value works as a 1 month interval in Rails, then. Why does Rails use  `2629746` seconds for 1 month, y'know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm unsure about the nuances of why Rails uses, say `2629746` as a representation of `1.month` in seconds, I've implemented a workaround for this scenario.

I wanted to keep the select input generated as-is by Rails, since the values it generates with (listed in the question) work great on the Rails end. That is, I can use that select seamlessly to select an interval to be used as an `ActiveSupport::Duration`. For this reason, I didn't want to change the select input.

Instead, I wrote a simple (albeit a bit hacky) function to do the correct moment operation depending on the value of the select:

```js
  addRailsSecondsStringToMoment(seconds_string, moment) {
    switch (seconds_string) {
      case "86400":
        moment.add(1, "days");
        break;
      case "259200":
        moment.add(3, "days");
        break;
      case "604800":
        moment.add(7, "days");
        break;
      case "1209600":
        moment.add(14, "days");
        break;
      case "2629746":
        moment.add(1, "months");
        break;
      case "7889238":
        moment.add(3, "months");
        break;
      case "15778476":
        moment.add(6, "months");
        break;
      case "31556952":
        moment.add(1, "years");
        break;
    }
  }
```

Then I can just call it like so:

```js
this.addRailsSecondsStringToMoment(this.sendFrequencySelectTarget.value, finalRunAt);
```

... where `finalRunAt` is a `moment` object. Could probably be a bit prettier, but it works. Happy to accept a sexier solution if someone posts one, especially if it provides some information on why Rails uses the seconds values it does.